# Understanding Go closures calling myinc := inc() vs inc()()

Tags: go, closures

I am learning go and working on closures.  I am slightly confused by the following;

```
func inc() func() int {
    var i int = 0
    return func() int {
        i++
        return i
    }
}

func main() {
    myinc := inc()
    fmt.Println(myinc())
    fmt.Println(myinc())
    fmt.Println(myinc())
}
```

This code results in printing 1, 2, 3 as expected.  What I am confused by is it is my understanding that calling `myinc()` is essentially the same as calling `inc()()`.  If I do the following:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(inc()())
    fmt.Println(inc()())
    fmt.Println(inc()())
}
```

I get a result of 1, 1, 1.

Am I misunderstanding what is happening in myinc := inc() vs inc()() ?  Could someone please explain to me what is happening here ?

Comment: `myinc()` calls the same function value using the same instance of the `i` variable. In case of `inc()()`, `inc()` always returns a new function value referring to a new instance of `i`, and calling its result like `inc()()` will use that new instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var i int = 0` is executed when you call `inc()`.

In your first code, `inc()` is called only once at `myinc := inc()`. In second code, `inc()` is called three times.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I never thought of inc() as being calling only 1 time, but this explanation really helped.